# 404 CodeIgniter - Wrong Segments?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm a PHP Developer and I've been asked to sort out a project that has been built already in CodeIgniter.  I hadn't used CodeIgniter before so I did a couple of tutorials to get up to speed.

The problem I'm having is when I download the project zip off GitHub, and install it, I get a CodeIgniter 404 page.

I debugged it to what I think is the source.  In `/system/Router.php`

If I put this line of code `print_r($segments); die();` at the beginning of the `_validate_request`  function in `/system/Router.php`, it prints this output:

```
Array ( [0] => site2 [1] => index.php [2] => about )
```

The URL is

```
http://127.0.0.1/site2/index.php/about
```

BUT

If I put the same piece of code in a fresh install of CodeIgniter, I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => welcome [1] => index )
```

Now.  It seems as though the site I'm working on has a certain way of routing that I don't understand.  Has anyone else come across this?  Am I just being a n00b?  I really hope I am

Comment: Check default controller of the project inside application/config/routes.php
And cross check have you done all config settings change in config.php

Comment: Thanks Naincy. I have this $route['default_controller'] = "home"; and the home controller appears to be present and correct. I've also tested other controllers in there with the same result.

Comment: check your $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
Is it Auto or something else.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter segmenting starts after your base_url.

$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.test.com/testsite/index.php';

So your segment should start after baseurl

Url: http://www.test.com/testsite/index.php/welcome/index/product/vehicle/14

Then Your segment would be

1st welcome (Controller name)
2nd index   (function name)
3rd product
4th vehicle
5th 14

Comment: Thanks Kunj. Unfortunatly, it was set as follows: $config['base_url'] = ''; And when I set it to http://127.0.0.1/site2/index.php, I still get the 404